# Conditional Formatting in Access with function in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, conditional-formatting

I'm familiar with programming in general but not with Access forms or VBA.

I have the conditional formatting working. Now I need to make it respond to the result of a custom VBA function.
Let's say there is a limit, based on the customer, to how many times something can happen.
The label will show the count, "Trip 3 of 5".
When we get to 5 of 5 it should be yellow and 6 of 5 should be red.
Note that I want the conditional formatting rules to be in Access, not in VBA. VBA just returns the value we test in the condition.

I don't see how to use the result of a VBA function in the conditional formatting expression, but it seems like you can use variables.

I tried

```
TripCountValid: GetTripCountValid(ID)
```

and then used TripCountValid in my condition, but that didn't seem to work.

GetTripCountMsg and GetTripCountValid are in the Orders module because that is where GetBillAcctMsg is, which I am emulating.
I could move it to the code-behind for the form.

My MsgBox in GetTripCountMsg gets called but not the one in GetTripCountValid.

Comment: Why don't you use a textbox to display the count? Have ConditionalFormatting reference that textbox. What you show looks like a calculated field in query. What and where exactly is TripCountValid?

Comment: An ID field is not normally edited so therefore AfterUpdate will not trigger.

Comment: @June7 The count message is in a textbox and is referenced by the formatting.

Comment: TripCountValid is in a module, but could be in the code for the form if that helped.

Comment: Why are you selecting ID from a combobox and what has that got to do with trip count? Sorry, can't make sense of what you describe. Programmatically setting textbox value does not trigger AfterUpdate.

Comment: @June7 The point is that the thing you choose in the drop down is the thing you are counting. Each one gets a certain number of trips. Choosing a different one gives a different count. Ignore setting it programatically. That just happens on first displaying the form if they've already filled it out.

Comment: And where are you saving these various trip counts? Where are you displaying these counts? ConditionalFormatting can reference a custom function that is behind the control's form/report or in general module. Most common is to reference a field/control on form/report or use domain aggregate function.

Comment: Everything about the trip is saved in the database and accessed by pass-through tables in Access. The message about the trip count is displayed in the textbox that we want to apply formatting to.

Comment: @June7 Now we are getting somewhere. How do I reference a custom function?

Comment: Very simply. Assuming your function returns a Boolean (True/False), CF rule like `Expression Is: GetTripCountValid([ID])`.

Comment: @June7 Please write this up as the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function can be referenced in Conditional Formatting. Use the `Expression Is:` option. Assuming your function returns a Boolean (True/False), the CF rule would simply be:

Expression Is: `GetTripCountValid([ID])`

Set the desired formatting to display if the function returns True. Or if you prefer to change display for False:

Expression Is: `NOT GetTripCountValid([ID])`

If those expressions are not explicit enough use = sign with whichever Boolean value you prefer.

Expression Is: `GetTripCountValid([ID]) = True`

If function returned something other than Boolean, use the last syntax to compare with whatever parameter appropriate for situation. The point is, the expression must evaluate to True or False.

Comment: I got it to work as GetTripCountValid() but not as GetTripCountValid([ID]). I shouldn't do the calculations twice anyway, so I marked this as a valid answer.